# Microdata+Schema.org for a list of manufactures you represent

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I was wondering what is the best way to structure (Microdata) a list of manufactures that a company represents.

I have the following example as a List. Would this work?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <div>
            <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                <div> 
                    <img itemprop=image data-src="/companyALogo.jpg" alt="Company A" />
                    <div>
                        <meta itemprop="position" content=0>
                        <div itemprop="name">Company A</div>
                        <div> 
                            <a itemprop="url" href="https://company/companyAPage"> More On Company A</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                <div> 
                    <img itemprop=image data-src="/companyALogo.jpg" alt="Company B" />
                    <div>
                        <meta itemprop="position" content=1>
                        <div itemprop="name">Company B</div>
                        <div> 
                            <a itemprop="url" href="https://company/companyBPage"> More On Company B</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                <div> 
                    <img itemprop=image data-src="/companyCLogo.jpg" alt="Company C" />
                    <div>
                        <meta itemprop="position" content=2>
                        <div itemprop="name">Company C</div>
                        <div> 
                            <a itemprop="url" href="https://company/companyCPage"> More On Company C</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structured data just conveys that there is a list of *something*, where each list item has a name and a URL. It does not convey the context for the list, and it does not convey what each list item is supposed to represent.

A manufacturer would usually be an [`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization), or more specifically a [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness).

The [`itemListElement`](https://schema.org/itemListElement) property allows you to provide `LocalBusiness` items directly, or you could use intermediate [`ListItem`](https://schema.org/ListItem) items, to which you can add the `LocalBusiness` items via the [`item`](https://schema.org/item) property.

```html
<div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
</div>
```

```html
<div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
  <div itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  </div>
</div>
```

Unless a consumer (like Google Search) requires the slightly more complex `ListItem` way for a specific feature, the only reason for using it would be if the item order is relevant. The reason is that Microdata doesn’t capture the order of the HTML elements, so you need to use the [`position`](https://schema.org/position) property if the order matters.

So now it’s clear that it’s a list of businesses, but it’s still not clear what the purpose of the list is. I’m not sure what "a list of manufactures that a company represents" means exactly, but if Schema.org offers a suitable property to convey this, it’s likely that it doesn’t work with an `ItemList`, but by providing multiple values for the property directly. So you might have to weigh up the disadvantages and advantages.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The company that I would like to implement this for resells a very large portfolio of products from many different companies. I would like to create an idea of association between this company and the companies it resells.

Comment: I had a look at "Organization". But, based off of the context. I was also looking at "Brand"

Comment: Google recommends just doing a list of items if it is a summary page: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings

Comment: Thanks Tony McCreath. That is what I was thinking. Google should be able to make the connection. The page name is Manufacturers and the WepPage name tag is manufacturers.